# What are these spots under the leaves in my cut flowers?

Tags: identification, leaves

I have got a bunch of flowers, and under the leaves I noticed that there are  a lot of spots. I do not know  what type of leaves they are and I am not sure if the spots are eggs. Should I be worried about them?

[image: leaves]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The leaves in the picture looks like ferns. As you may know, ferns use [spores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore) to reproduce. It appears to me that it is just the [Sori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorus) under your leaves (the Sori is made up of groups of [Sporangium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporangium), which produce and contain the spores).  Nothing to be worry about!
You can even try to grow more from these.

Comment: I agree these definitely look like fern spores to me too